# How to log all requests for an http4s client

Tags: scala, http4s

I want to log all the requests my application makes. The application makes several call like this:

```
val client: Client = org.http4s.client.blaze.SimpleHttp1Client(...)
client.fetch(Request(method = GET, uri = aUri))
```

Is there a way of getting the client to log to a file all the requests?

(Using v0.12.4)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got it working:

- maven
- https: 0.20.0-M6
- slf4j-api: 1.7.26
- slf4j-log4j12: 1.7.26

Based on the question, you have to modify your code to this:

```
import org.http4s.client.middleware.Logger

val client: Client = org.http4s.client.blaze.SimpleHttp1Client(...)
Logger(logBody = true, logHeaders = true)(client)
    .fetch(Request(method = GET, uri = aUri))
```

So you have to wrap the client with a Logger

Answer (score 1):

You can use the provided middleware in http4s version 0.23.14:

```scala
import org.http4s.client.Client
import org.http4s.client.middleware.RequestLogger
import cats.effect.IO

def client: Client[IO] = ???
val clientWithRequestLogging: Client[IO] = RequestLogger(logHeaders = true, logBody = true)(client)
```

`clientWithRequestLogging` can then be used in the usual way `Client[F]` is used. Example:

```
clientWithRequestLogging.fetch(Request(method = GET, uri = aUri))
```